# qt5 build failing on raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, qt5

I'm trying to follow [this guide](https://wiki.qt.io/Native_Build_of_Qt5_on_a_Raspberry_Pi) to build qt5 on raspberry pi and I'm running into an error.

After following the script I'm at the stage where I execute make, and I run into this error:

[link to error (too long to paste)](http://pastebin.com/bxm48CeQ)

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the relevant libraries and possible the directories where to find the libraries.
Take a look at the answer to [this question](http://you%20also%20need%20to%20specify%20the%20relevant%20libraries%20and%20possible%20the%20directories%20where%20to%20find%20the%20libraries).